# Where in the HTTP Request does the entered domain name get sent to the server? - SSL/TLS validation

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy, traefik

I am dealing with an issue in Docker using a reverse proxy where the reverse proxy (Traefik, if you are familiar) uses Docker's internal DNS resolution scheme to send requests to other internal networked services.

That's fine, except when the reverse proxy does a redirect of the original request to one of those services that is exposed internally via TLS and has a valid, signed CA certificate, it causes a problem because the request to said service is done as `https://<ipaddress>:<port>/...` rather than using `https://<domainname_enteredfromclient>:<port>/...` I think this is causing the breakdown unless I'm understanding it fundamentally wrong.

What's happening is the reverse proxy does not trust/cannot validate the certificate because it is signed using a specific domain name, and it is already resolving to a specific IP address given by Docker at runtime in order to make its request to the other service (the redirect).

How is this different than being on the top level, host machine, entering a **domain name** in the URL as part of a request, and having a DNS resolving to an IP address? Where does that original domain name that the user typed in get stored in the request so that name can be validated against the CA certificate? Is there a request header? Or is this totally service/browser dependent?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, IP addresses in URL, while technically possible, will create more problems than anything else, even more so for HTTPS since for certificate validation the server name will be needed. The servername is sent in the HTTP `Host:` header.

Comment: Thanks. So if I were to (from remote client) use curl -H and pass in the header, and on traefik enable 'passHostHeader' option, theoretically, the host header would be the one to validate the TLS certificate? Or, again, is this up to implementation of the reverse proxy? I.E. maybe they use the host header to validate, maybe they don't...

Comment: The HTTPS client is provided with a URL. That URL contains a hostname. The certificate that is returned must contain that hostname in  one of the designated fields of the certificate. The way the addresses are resolved of no importance to the HTTPS client, as long as it gets the correct certificate from the server. This is specified in RFC 2818.

Comment: James, thanks - I read RFC and got the impression that it is up to the actual service to implement/decide how it wants to validate the host name the certificate provides against the host name the end user has entered as a URL to the client. Correct? If true, I can only conclude that the traefik client breaks this model when it redirects to the backend service, manipulating the original host name passed in by the user (probably ignoring it), and deciding to use the IP address of the backend - thereby making it impossible for itself to validate the certificate domain name against an IP address.

Comment: James - In other words, if the address gets resolved prior to the request to the backend, and the reverse proxy Traefik decides to send the redirect request as "https://<IP>:<port>.. Then it will make a big difference, because there is no correct host name to validate against the certificate.. The host name is now an IP address in the scope of the redirect request. That's why the 'Bad Certificate' error is happening. I'd like to reconfirm that it is true: it's up to the reverse proxy Traefik to include functionality to store the original end user typed hostname and validate against that, yes?

Comment: No because the server needs to know the name (TLS SNI mechanism) to decide which certificate to send back. Imagine multiple sites on the same IP: if the client connects without giving the name how is the server supposed to know which one is the relevant one?

Comment: Patrick I believe you are right. This is simply a matter of Traefik reverse proxy not currently having SNI capability. There is no config option to allow for indication of the server name. This does not mean, however, that the reverse proxy cannot connect to the backend service. Only that, perhaps the backend service does not know which certificate to return, or that it does return it, but Treafik, having no indication of the server name (only the IP and port) verifies that this is not the correct requested host name (since we requested only using the IP). If you confirm answer I will upvote.